Combinatorics Card Counting Problem
Found the following problem in a 2019 CS109 free open online course on probability from Stanford:
You are counting cards in a card game that uses four standard decks of cards. There are 208 cards total. Each deck has 52 cards (13 values each with 4 suits). Cards are only
distinguishable based on their suit and value, not which deck they came from.
You are dealt two cards. How many distinct pairs of cards can you be dealt? Note: the
order of the two cards you are dealt does not matter.
Is this just: $\frac{(52\times52)}{2}$
Or am I missing something?

I don't think so you missing anything, answer seems fine

I am sorry but the answer is not correct

An easy way to see this method cannot be correct is to imagine what would happen if there were only $51$ cards in a deck.

Your answer is incorrect. The problem with your answer is the fact, that you didn't notice that some of the pairs are counted twice and some of them just once.
The solution should go as follows. There are $2$ cases:
Case 1: You are given two the same cards (this is possible since you have more than one deck).
Since there are $52$ different cards, thus you have exactly $52$ such pairs $(a, a)$.
Case 2: You are given two different cards.
Now there are $52$ ways to choose first card and $51$ ways to choose the second (since it must be different from the first). But we must divide the result by $2$ since we have counted twice the pairs $(a, b)$ and $(b,a)$, which are in fact the same.
Thus there are:
$$
\boxed{52 + \frac{52 \times 51}{2}}
$$
such pairs in total.

I get it now, thanks!

But notice that cards from different decks are indistinguishable, so we don't have to care about the deck where do they come from

However your comment led me to edit my answer to notice that since we have $4$ decks my case 1 is possible (what i didn't really think about before)
